# Error when use listbox to display data in function

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I want to display data in listbox , but I can not  use listBox1 in function , I declare it in program but can not use in function , how can I use listBox1 in function to display data

```
void threetask(ref Int32 x,ref Int32 y)
{
  //do something
  listBox1.Items.Add(x);//error
  listBox1.Items.Add(y);//error
}


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
   this.Controls.Add(listBox1);
   threetask(ref x,ref y);
}
```

Comment: You should google for local variables scope

Answer (score 1):

Here control scope is the problem. Please try to declare listbox1 outside your function. Then you will be able to access it through other methods. Try this one.

```
ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   WindowsFormsApplication2 app2=new WindowsFormsApplication2();
   this.Controls.Add(app2.listBox1);

   threetask(ref x,ref y);
}

void threetask(ref Int32 x,ref Int32 y)
{
   //do something
   // To get rid of your last error regarding static property or method.
   WindowsFormsApplication2 app2=new WindowsFormsApplication2();
   app2.listBox1.Items.Add(x);

   app2.listBox1.Items.Add(y);
}
```

Comment: I write this code but error "Error 5 Ambiguity between 'WindowsFormsApplication2.Form2.listBox1' and 'WindowsFormsApplication2.Form2.listBox1'

Comment: Error "Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication2.Form2.listBox1'

Comment: It looks like you are calling a non static property from a static method. You will need to either make the property static, or create an instance of WindowsFormsApplication2

Comment: plz can you explain more, i am beginner in c#

Comment: here are two use-full links to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx